# Automatically Navigate a User to a new ViewController in Swift 3.0 after Login

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, viewcontroller

Goal:

1. After a User successfully logs into the App (via Firebase), the next time the User launches the App we automatically navigate the User to a new LoginViewController to skip the initial login ViewController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy way is to store the [user data in UserDefaults](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-save-user-settings-using-userdefaults). (id, token, or what ever u need to re login or keep session next time app is open).

Next time app launch check if there's a user logged in or not.

Remember to remove the user from UserDefaults if he logs out.

Comment: Thanks @alegelos for your answer, here is another question if you would like to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46717839/add-modal-popup-to-map-annotation-swift-3-0