# Add Modal Popup to Map Annotation - Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, popup, mkmapview

I have a number of custom pins on a map and when a user taps a pin and then the button on the `Callout View` I would would to add a function that launches a `Modal Popup` using Scene Dock

Here is my code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    // here I would like to launch a Modal Popup using Scene Dock

    popInfo.center = view.center
    popInfo.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.8, y: 1.2)
    self.view.addSubview(popInfo)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [], animations: {
        self.dimView.alpha = 0.8
        self.popInfo.transform = .identity
       })
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Rob, thanks for your answer - to clarify when a user taps on the button in the Callout View I would like to launch a blank Modal Popup that displays over the current ViewController

Comment: Hi @Rob - to answer your second comment: Do do you want a callout with a button that you can then tap to show some other pop up view? Yes and I would like to launch the blank Modal Popup over the current ViewController (centre the Modal Popup) using Scene Dock - thanks

Comment: It looks like you are adding `popInfo` as subview, so what precisely is not working?

Comment: I suspect we'll need you to produce a reproducible example of the problem, as I don't think the above is sufficient.